# Can a fragment change its layout from within itself?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible for a fragment to change its layout at run time.

In my case the fragment by default shows the IP address and SSID of wifi when wifi is disabled or disconnected the fragment needs to udpate its layout to a new layout and similarly revert to previous layout when wifi is back.

I know that one way is to create another fragment and callback the activity which will replace the fragment but I wanted to maintain the wifi related logic and UI within one fragment.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a non visible `View` component that you can make visible when a certain condition is met. That is, when you sense a change in your WiFi state, you make that invisible `View`, visible.

One possible implementation is to subscribe the `Fragment` to an event bus (like [`Otto`](https://square.github.io/otto)) and update itself when you publish to the bus that the state has changed.

Comment: Thanks I guess this solution will work, I will try it out and then mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view switcher to do this.  Here is the documentation https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fwidget%2FViewSwitcher.html&ei=8ISIU_KuIKH17AbOkIDAAw&usg=AFQjCNHXHron7bvL13HXhNDo84CjyWvnPg&sig2=xu9L3m1vhY4VKibCB4a11Q&bvm=bv.67720277,d.ZGU